How can I obtain forgotten A&P certificate numbers?
I lost my A&P years ago after leaving the airlines and do not remember the certificate numbers.
I got my licenses around 1999. Does anyone know the process for obtaining the certs?  (Do not remember if the FAA used SSNs as cert #'s back then).

According to this the FAA stopped using SSNs for certificate numbers in 2002.  Although, my recollection is that there was a transition period beforehand (maybe it was optional to not use it for a few years?).  So, there's a good chance that it is your SSN.
In any case, you can get in touch with a local FSDO and they should be able to issue you a new ATP card, as well as provide other information, once you identify yourself (SSN, prior address etc)

Thank you for the advice. I was trying to process it online since I'm currently residing overseas, but will make it a point to visit a FSDO next time Im in the US.
